# Establishing an IPv6 connection using sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ipv6

I am trying to run this very basic socket example:

```
import socket
host = 'ipv6hostnamegoeshere'
port=9091

ourSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
ourSocket.connect((host, port))
```

Yet, I get the error:

```
    ourSocket.connect((host, port))
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The boolean has_ipv6 returns true. Any help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the [socket.connect docs](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) says, `AF_INET6` expects a 4-tuple:

> sockaddr is a tuple describing a
>   socket address, whose format depends
>   on the returned family (a (address,
>   port) 2-tuple for AF_INET, a (address,
>   port, flow info, scope id) 4-tuple for
>   AF_INET6), and is meant to be passed
>   to the socket.connect() method.

For example:

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo("www.python.org", 80, 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP)
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('82.94.164.162', 80)),
 (10, 1, 6, '', ('2001:888:2000:d::a2', 80, 0, 0))]

>>> ourSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
>>> ourSocket.connect(('2001:888:2000:d::a2', 80, 0, 0))
```