# I am trying to use IPv6 address on Socket (Python)

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to use my IPv6 address on Socket, but when I enter the text I want to send over to the device the IPv6 address is linked to, it just stops and closes the terminal.

```
import sys, os
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
while True:
    SERVER_IP   = '[Hidden for security reasons]'
    PORT_NUMBER = 5000
    SIZE = 1024
    print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port {1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))

    mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
    myMessage = input('Enter your message: \n')
    mySocket.sendto(myMessage.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
    clr = os.system('cls')
```

Comment: For starters, you may want to drop the shell call to `cls` to see what if any error you get and call your script from a terminal to observe the behavior. Then you may want to check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families), because the error you're not seeing is likely related to trying to use (here not displayed) IPv6 address for `AF_INET` domain (with a two tuple) and not `AF_INET6` (with a four tuple).

Comment: You want to use `AF_INET6` and although a 2 tuple can be used, you may want to expand it to `(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER,0,0)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an exception being thrown. Run your script from a terminal that doesn’t close when completed and you’ll see the error.

The built in IDLE editor will work just fine for this. (I assume you’re on Windows since that’s the platform where there are terminals that close on process exit)

Edit: as for the error, I think you got the parameters wrong. It has been answered here: [Establishing an IPv6 connection using sockets in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358021/establishing-an-ipv6-connection-using-sockets-in-python)

Comment: Alright, so here is my error.

Exception has occurred: gaierror
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
  File "C:\Users\Jacob B\Documents\1 Code\Python\Networking\Test client 1.py", line 13, in <module>
    mySocket.sendto(myMessage.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))

And I do not understand it.

Comment: @BnDLett_Coding - Also change your code to `AF_INET6`. I think sockets is trying to use the ipv6 address as a host name.

Comment: @tdelaney So basically like this?
```import sys, os
from socket import socket, AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM
while True:
    SERVER_IP   = '[removed for security reasons]'
    PORT_NUMBER = 5000
    SIZE = 1024
    print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port {1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))

    mySocket = socket( AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM )
    myMessage = input('Enter your message: \n')
    mySocket.sendto(myMessage.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
    clr = os.system('cls')```

Comment: That looks right to me. On my home network I get "Network is unreachable" because my internet provider doesn't route it.