# ipv6 python sockets not working ! OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, sockets, ipv6

I have a simple client server program and the server side works but for some reason I can't get the the client to interact to the server. I am able to launch the server and use `nc -6 fe80::cbdd:d3da:5194:99be%eth1 2020` and connect to it.

Server code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
from socket import *
from time import ctime

HOST='::'
PORT = 2020
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM)
##tcpSerSock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while True:
        print('Waiting for connection...')

        tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
        print('...connected from:', addr)

        while True:
                data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
                if not data:
                        break
                tcpCliSock.send(('[%s] %s'%(bytes(ctime(), 'utf-8'), data)).encode('utf-8'))
        tcpCliSock.close()
tcpSerSock.close()
```

client code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
from socket import *





def tcp_ipv6():
    HOST = 'fe80::cbdd:d3da:5194:99be%eth1'
    PORT = 2020
    ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
    BUFSIZ = 1024
    
    sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect(ADDR)
    
    while True:
        data = input('> ')
        if not data:
            break
        sock.send(data)
        response = sock.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not response:
            break
        print(response.decode('utf-8'))
    sock.close()        
   
tcp_ipv6()
```

When I run the client code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 44, in <module>
    tcp_ipv6() 
  File "client.py", line 31, in tcp_ipv6
    sock.connect(ADDR)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Edit1:
Thanks to [Establishing an IPv6 connection using sockets in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358021/establishing-an-ipv6-connection-using-sockets-in-python)

4-tuple for AF_INET6

```
ADDR = (HOST, PORT, 0, 0)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
sock.connect(ADDR)
```

Still having the same error

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The higher level function - `create_connection` , to connect to port works in such case. Sample scriptlet is given as follows. Though why sock.connect fails needs to be identified.

```
HOST = "xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%en0"
PORT = 2020
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
BUFSIZ = 1024

sock=create_connection(ADDR)
```

Comment: new error when I launch client on raspberry trying to connect on the server launched on ubunto

 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 48, in <module>
    tcp_ipv6() 
  File "client.py", line 32, in tcp_ipv6
    sock=create_connection(ADDR)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
`

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of your question have been asked before.

[Establishing an IPv6 connection using sockets in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358021/establishing-an-ipv6-connection-using-sockets-in-python)

However, it is not the entire reason why it is not working correctly. If you look at your IPv6 address. `fe80::cbdd:d3da:5194:99be%eth1` You can see the `%eth1` at the end. That is not part of the internet address. Change `HOST` to `HOST = 'fe80::cbdd:d3da:5194:99be'`. And it should work.

I would also like to point out another error in your code. You are attempting to send a string (received from input) over the socket. However, this method only accepts byte like objects. You can add `data = data.encode('utf-8')` to fix this.

Comment: If a similar question already exists, please flag or vote it as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @bobveringa, 
It didn't work, I still have the same error,
I changed ADDR to `ADDR = (HOST, PORT, 0, 0)` and `sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)`

Comment: @naoussa You had another error in your code, I've updated the answer. I ran it on my machine, and it seems to work now.

Comment: @bobveringa Thank you, your last edit, data = data.encode('utf-8'), was helpful.